# Scheduler job does not execute on specified interval

Tags: java, cron, jira, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have created `jira plugin scheduler job` which executes specified job class.

here, I am not able to execute scheduler job on specified interval as I have defined.

Below is stuff where schedule the interval:

here, scheduling start date as - `current date (00: 00:00)` start of the day and

interval as `(long) (15 * 3600000))` (where 15 is in hour).

stuff should have execute on 3 PM but it does not execute on that time and executed other time randomly.

```
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();               
startDate.set(startDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), startDate.get(Calendar.DATE),0,0,0);

pluginScheduler.scheduleJob(schedulerUniqueKey,                       
      // unique name of the job
      DailyReportService.class,     // class of the job
      new HashMap<String,Object>() {{
            put("1", DailyReportImpl.this);
       }},                          // data that needs to be passed to the job
      startDate.getTime(),          // the time the job is to start
      intervalInMilisections);
```

Can you please suggest what is wrong and how it could be schedule.

Comment: You set the start date as Today at 0AM. Did the schedule trigger? You setting a start date in the past, not in some date that will be achieved. Or am I wrong? In this case, you can set a future date, like tomorrow at 0am.

Comment: No, scheduler does not trigger. I set the start date as start of current day example: current date time as : 1st April 2013 01:30:55 PM then, i use the start date as "1st April 2013 00:00:00" in schedule job and delay as "54000000" milisecond (15 hours) so, i expect it to execute on 3 PM but it does not work as expected.

Comment: I do set day as start of the day (00:00:00) because, i need to execute scheduler on time basis so, set the delay related to time.

Comment: Did you try to put tomorrow as start date with no delay and see if runs? Maybe the delay doesn't work because never pass through the start date.

Comment: ok, so i tried by putting "0" as dealy then it gives me an error for "repeatInterval must be greater than zero" so, i tried by giving 1000 milisecond as below: </br> pluginScheduler.scheduleJob(
           schedulerUniqueKey,                   // unique name of the job
           DailyReportService.class, 
                 new HashMap<String,Object>() {{
                     put("1", DailyReportImpl.this);
                 }},                         
                 startDate.getTime(), 1000); //here start date as next day with 00:00:00

Comment: as above comment, this was not working and not able to get notification by changing to next day and time there. what is wrong with this..so, not able to recognize start date and delay in scheduleJob..?